# Perl: Printing the values of a hash cause error: use of uninitialized value within %hashtable in array dereference

Tags: perl, hash, hashtable

```
my %hashTable;   #created my hash

while ()
{
    #i read through a file and store each word in the file to the hash like so 

    push @{ $hashTable {$key}}, $word;

} #end of while

#store values of anonymous array at key $key in array values
@values= @{ $hashTable {$key} };
```

However I get an error when I compile saying

```
use of uninitialized value within %hashtable in array dereference at....
```

I would like to be able to retrieve the values from the hash in the anonymous array.

Comment: Post your code and input data.

Answer (score 1):

That is due to `$hashTable{$key}` being undefined instead of an array reference. It's possible that this is because there's no element with key `$key`.

```
$ perl -wE'my %h; my $k="foo"; $h{$k}=[] if $ARGV[0]; my @a=@{$h{$k}};' 0
Use of uninitialized value within %h in array dereference at -e line 1.

$ perl -wE'my %h; my $k="foo"; $h{$k}=[] if $ARGV[0]; my @a=@{$h{$k}};' 1

$
```

Comment: Presumably because the while loop didn't run once.  (Don't you hate debugging incomplete code?  That's an eternal loop …)

Comment: @TheSidhekin sorry its not an eternal loop. I just did not want to bore you guys with little details but really its opening a file while ($line = <IN>)  
{ ...... do something
 my $word=$line

Comment: He was explaining why he claimed the code you posted wasn't the code you ran: The code you you posted has an infinite loop that prevents the print statement from being reached.

Comment: Anyway, his point was that you're doing everyone including yourself a disfavour by posting code that does not exhibit the problem you describe. We would have been able to help you far better if you had.